# "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" issue in react using axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have an api call like below in react using Axios.

```
axios({
            url: 'some url',
            method: 'get'
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
```

and while running the app Im getting the below error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'some url' No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3003' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve the issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765/5915572

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: Try https://crossorigin.me/ , remove during production.